# Inserting values of key=>value array into a mysql table (php)

Tags: php, mysql

I am very very new to MySQL, I have two arrays, whose output looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Product/service
    [1] => Product/service
    [2] => Non-profit organization
    [3] => Community
    [4] => Company
    [5] => Non-profit organization
    [6] => Website
    [7] => Book
    [8] => Arts/humanities website
    [9] => Public figure
)
```

I have a table (with a variable name) and two column names, the above array is called "category" and I would like to have a table where there would be a column named "category" which would just list these elements. I have tried the code below but it does nothing:

```
mysql_connect('127.0.0.1','root','') or die(mysql_error());;
mysql_select_db("DBName") or die(mysql_error());;
mysql_query("CREATE TABLE `".$tablename."` ( category VARCHAR(30), name VARCHAR(30))");

foreach($category as $k=>$v)
{
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO".$tablename. "(category) VALUES".$v); 

}
```

Comment: I do not see where `$tablename` is being set

Comment: You should avoid using `mysql_*` functions. As of `PHP 5.5.0` they are deprecated. Use something like [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: Look at the `INSERT` syntax.  `INSERT INTO (category) VALUES ('value')` You're missing `()`.

Comment: You need some error checking. `if (!mysql_query(...)) echo mysql_error()` and you'll see it's complaining about syntax errors in the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need some more white space and some extra punctuation:

```
mysql_query('INSERT INTO '.$tablename. ' (category) VALUES ('.$v.')');
```

Answer (score 2):

I understand that you're new so let me see if I can help you. Some people like being creating with their php, as opposed to me where I like it clear and concise as to what is happening.

So here try this:

```
foreach($categories as $key=>$val){

      $sql_I = "INSERT INTO categories SET category = '{$val}'";
      $res_I = mysql_query($sql_I) or die(mysql_error());
}
```